# Dell XPS 17 9700 internal microphone issue

Tags: 20.04, kernel, dell, xps, oem

Dell XPS 17 9700
BIOS version: 1.7.2
OS version: 20.04.2 LTS
Kernel: 5.10.0-1029-oem --> linux-oem-20.04b package.

I had an audio issue with Dell XPS 17 9700.
I found the solution on dell forum 2nd post:
https://www.dell.com/community/XPS/DELL-XPS-17-9700-Ubuntu-Debian-Linux/td-p/7861072

Sound is back after kernel actualization from linux-oem-20.04b package. Internal microphone still doesn't work. It apears in audio settings [(Mic in OS settings)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zm88p.png). But there is no input. I tried to set various [Alsamixer settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dAnoO.png) but with no success. I turned audio off and on in BIOS but it's not a solution.

I have also some [ACPI error messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBSQJ.png). As a Linux newbie I have no idea how to investigate them.

[enter image description here][4]

- Is any kernel package tested with XPS 17?
- What could I check to investigate the problem?
- My temporary solution is to use bluetooth mic.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to explain what you mean by “There are a lot of issues”? What specific problems are you seeing? Which kernel are *you* running? This will make it much easier to provide possible solutions without guessing wrong and wasting everyone’s time …

Comment: FYI, there is a [forum](https://www.dell.com/community/Linux-Developer-Systems/bd-p/a-4613-en-forums) on Dell's web site for Linux users.  You can consider asking there as well.

Comment: @matigo Thanks. You have right. Edited.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same issue after an upgrade to the 5.10.0-1029-oem kernel. Now I am on version 5.10.0-1051-oem and I fixed the Issue by switching the rt715 ADC 24 Mux selector in alsamixer to DMIC3.

[image: Press F6 to select the sof-soundwire soundcard]

[image: Set rt715 ADC 24 Mux to DMIC3]

Answer (score 1):

There is solution which works out of the box with 5.11.0-27-generic kernel and newer. Simply use command below to install it.

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-20.04
```